# ACL mask assigned when a group member creates files/directories on a Samba server from Windows effectively make them read-only

Tags: windows, samba, access-control-list

Home directories are shared by Samba running on CentOS 6.3 with the following configuration:

```
[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        read only = No
        inherit acls = Yes
        inherit owner = Yes
        browseable = No
        csc policy = disable
```

The Samba server is joined to an active directory domain where the user *applefoo* is a member of the group *domain admins* and the user *bananabar* is a member of the group *domain users*. The desktop of *bananabar* is redirected to *\\samba\bananabar\Desktop* which has the following ACEs:

```
# file: Desktop/
# owner: bananabar
# group: domain\040users
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:domain\040admins:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:domain\040admins:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

When *bananabar* creates a file/directory on his desktop, they are created with the following ACEs:

```
# file: New Folder by bananabar
# owner: bananabar
# group: domain\040users
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:domain\040admins:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:domain\040admins:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

# file: New Text Document by bananabar.txt
# owner: bananabar
# group: domain\040users
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:domain\040admins:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r--
```

On the other hand, when *applefoo* creates files/directories in *\\samba\bananabar\Desktop*, they are created with the following ACEs:

```
# file: New Folder by applefoo
# owner: bananabar
# group: domain\040users
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:domain\040admins:rwx      #effective:r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:domain\040admins:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

# file: New Text Document by applefoo.txt
# owner: bananabar
# group: domain\040users
user::rwx
group::r-x      #effective:r--
group:domain\040admins:rwx      #effective:r--
mask::r--
other::r--
```

The only difference between the two is the mask where the files/directories created by *applefoo* are effectively read-only for the group *domain admins*. How do I get *applefoo* to create files/directories with the same ACEs as *bananabar*? Are the masks assigned by Samba or is Windows responsible for it? This happens whether I create them using Windows XP, Windows 7, or Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score -2):

```
create mask = 770
directory mask = 770
force directory mode = 0700
```

Comment: This answer needs an explanation.